# How can I override a jQuery event handler of an id selector with a class selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I have click event handlers for several elements with id and class selectors:

```
$(function() {
    $("#cancelOrderLink").click(function() {
        if (confirm("If you continue, all items will be removed " +
            "from your cart. This action cannot be undone. Continue " +
            "and empty cart?"))
            $("form#clearCartForm").submit();
    });

    $(".updateItemLink").click(function(){
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    })
});
```

However, I want to add logic to prevent these handlers from being triggered if the element has a specific class name:

```
$(function() {
    $(".superUser").click(function() {
        $("#message").html("This action is not allowed when acting as a Super User.<br />");

        return false;
    });
});
```

How can I override the handlers in the first snippet with the second snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Add `event.stopPropagation();` to your code:

```
$(".superUser").click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   ...
```

Alternatively, if the elements are equal, and you don't have any other `click` listeners, unbind the previous method:

```
$(".superUser").unbind('click').click(function() {
```

If you want to bind the events at run-time for the specific IDs, but not the class name, use:

```
$("#cancelOrderLink").not('.superuser').click(function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) filter.

```
$(function() {
    $("#cancelOrderLink").not(".superUser").click(function() {
        if (confirm("If you continue, all items will be removed " +
            "from your cart. This action cannot be undone. Continue " +
            "and empty cart?"))
            $("form#clearCartForm").submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of e.stopPropagation(), I would suggest using "return false". It is a more foolproof way to stop propagation and prevent defaults. 
 for example:

```
$("#yourclass").click(function(){
return flase;
});
```

Comment: Just think what you need. stopPropagation is exactly what is needed, as you would not want to let that event bubble any further, the other things return false does besides stopping propagation (via calling the very same function, https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.1/src/event.js#L393-L396) are not needed in this scenario. (it also stops callback execution) Read this link: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/ !